# Excel VBA move select items from listbox to a listbox in a differnt form that will be another popup userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

i have a workbook that has a Listbox that people can select multiple rows. i want to take that information once selected to another ListBox in a new form that will pop up once selected.

i found examples that transfer between listboxes in the same userform, but i need help moving them between different Forms.

this code shows how to pass information between two user forms on the same Form. But I need to modify this to move it between two different forms. Like if you click a submit button and another listbox with textboxes pops up.

```
Option Explicit
'Move Listbox Items in UserForm
'code from Dave Peterson
'posted on www.contextures.com


    Private Sub BTN_moveAllLeft_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
    Next iCtr

    Me.ListBox2.Clear
End Sub


Private Sub BTN_moveAllRight_Click()

Dim iCtr As Long

For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
Next iCtr

Me.ListBox1.Clear
End Sub


Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedLeft_Click()

Dim iCtr As Long

For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
    End If
Next iCtr

For iCtr = Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.ListBox2.RemoveItem iCtr
    End If
Next iCtr

End Sub


Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedRight_Click()

Dim iCtr As Long

For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
    End If
Next iCtr

For iCtr = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem iCtr
    End If
Next iCtr

End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim iCtr As Long

With Me.ListBox1
    For iCtr = 1 To 10
        .AddItem "This is a test" & iCtr
    Next iCtr
End With

With Me.ListBox2
    For iCtr = 1 To 10
        .AddItem "This is a not a test" & iCtr
    Next iCtr
End With

Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
Me.ListBox2.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you see `Me` you can reference a different userform.

For example, I have two userforms `UserForm1` and `UserForm2`.  Let's say our initial ListBox, `ListBox1` is on `UserForm1` and contains a list of colors.  `UserForm1` also contains a command button, `CommandButton1` that will move the selected items from `UserForm1` to a different listbox (also called `ListBox1`) in `UserForm2` to the next form.

The code in `UserForm1`, the initial form shown, the code on the command button would look like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            UserForm2.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(i)
        End If
    Next i

    UserForm2.Show


End Sub
```